# Error starting archive: Could not resolve type for sub-document partition key

Tags: mongodb, archive, atlas-data-lake

On creation of Online archive, it throws an error

My example Document

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "6098db2eea9ab45266fa48d1"
  },
  "aPlayers": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "606459f1cfc33a6ff919cae7"
      },
      "sName": "chrome_c....."
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "6073eb423f525f31df551fe9"
      },
      "sName": "ie_chetan...."
    }
  ],
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1620630339478"
    }
  }
}
```

Indexed : **updatedAt_1_aPlayers._id_1**

I am trying online archive with partition fields
Archive date field : **updatedAt**
Second most commonly queried field: **aPlayers._id**

```
updatedAt > aPlayers._id
```

It throws an error

**Error starting archive: Could not resolve type for field 'aPlayers._id'**

Comment: `updatedAt` is in date formai, but `aPlayers._id` is an ObjectId. How do you compare both?

Comment: i am not comparing that

Comment: i want to archive data on the basis of age, and i have entered Second most commonly queried field as aPlayers._id

Comment: may i know what do you mean by **I am trying online archive with partition updatedAt > aPlayers._id**

Comment: its partition field primary is updatedAt and second optional is aPlayers._id

Comment: I feel your question is not clear, Could you please update the question more clearly?

Comment: I added more info to explain in details i hope it clear to you now